# bash, getting exit status in pipe

Tags: bash, pipe

I'm running some test scripts with this command, so I can see the test output & have a log of the output. How can I access the exit status of "python test.py", or exit if "python test.py" fails

```
python test.py 2>&1 | tee -a tests.log
```

Comment: Take a look at the `PIPESTATUS` variable.

Comment: Take a look at the `PIPESTATUS` array.